# Efficiently selecting rows where a row in a related table exists

Tags: mysql, performance, percona, mysql-5.7, percona-xtradb-cluster

I've got a recurring pattern in a system that I'm currently working on, where, for example, I need to select all the users that have orders under a list of possible companies. Or needing to select users if a record of this user being flagged exists.

My `users` table contains 430,825 records, so this shouldn't really be that difficult to deal with. Right now I'm close, I have a query that get's that .047s execution time that I look for, but if I add one more piece to this, it gets real slow.

Here's my current query, the fast one:

```
select`UserID`
from`users`
where(`CompanyID`in('3e55d1bb-d8b6-11e4-b38f-b8ca3a83b4c8')
    or`UserID`in(select*
        from(select`UserID`
            from`invoices`
            where`CompanyID`in('3e55d1bb-d8b6-11e4-b38f-b8ca3a83b4c8')
            and`__Active`=1)`a`)
    or`UserID`in(select*
        from(select`UserID`
            from`quoterequests`
            where`CompanyID`in('3e55d1bb-d8b6-11e4-b38f-b8ca3a83b4c8')
            and`__Active`=1)`a`))
and(`UserID`in(select*
        from(select`UserID`
            from`userassociations`
            where`_Email`='brian@yeet.com'
            and`__Active`=1)`a`))
and(`UserID`in(select*
        from(select`UserID`
            from`usercustomerflags`
            where`CustomerFlagID`in(10,27,17,1,2,3,4,5,6)
            and`__Active`=1)`a`)
    or not exists(select 1 
        from`usercustomerflags`
        where`__Active`=1 
        and`users`.`UserID`=`UserID`))
and`Deleted`=0 
order by`DateTimeAdded`desc 
limit 50;
```

(The extra `select*from(...)` is because of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1434712/728236)

In the middle there, I'm pulling users by further by email address, while checking other related tables for emails that might be related to this user. Like, the next piece searches users including their CC addresses when quotes are sent out to customers.

```
select`UserID`
from`users`
where(`CompanyID`in('3e55d1bb-d8b6-11e4-b38f-b8ca3a83b4c8')
    or`UserID`in(select*
        from(select`UserID`
            from`invoices`
            where`CompanyID`in('3e55d1bb-d8b6-11e4-b38f-b8ca3a83b4c8')
            and`__Active`=1)`a`)
    or`UserID`in(select*
        from(select`UserID`
            from`quoterequests`
            where`CompanyID`in('3e55d1bb-d8b6-11e4-b38f-b8ca3a83b4c8')
            and`__Active`=1)`a`))
and(`UserID`in(select*
        from(select`UserID`
            from`userassociations`
            where`_Email`='brian@yeet.com'
            and`__Active`=1)`a`)
    or`UserID`in(select*
        from(select`UserID`
            from`userquotesemails`
            where`Email`='brian@yeet.com'
            and`__Active`=1)`a`))
and(`UserID`in(select*
        from(select`UserID`
            from`usercustomerflags`
            where`CustomerFlagID`in(10,27,17,1,2,3,4,5,6)
            and`__Active`=1)`a`)
    or not exists(select 1 
        from`usercustomerflags`
        where`__Active`=1 
        and`users`.`UserID`=`UserID`))
and`Deleted`=0 
order by`DateTimeAdded`desc 
limit 50;
```

I've added the alternate table to search for emails, but now the query takes 3.016s, which is way, way slower. It seems odd that, as I was building this query, that last part seemed to be the tipping point in performance here, what would be the cause of this?

The first and second explains, respectively

```
+----+--------------------+-------------------+--+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+------+-----------------------+---+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | <subquery6>       |  | ALL            |                                                                                             |                              |      |                       |   | 0.00  | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | users             |  | eq_ref         | PRIMARY,UserID_UNIQUE,fk_users_1_idx,users_Customers                                        | PRIMARY                      |  144 | <subquery6>.UserID    | 1 | 50.00 | Using where                     |
|  6 | MATERIALIZED       | userassociations  |  | ref            | userassociations_UserID,userassociations__Email                                             | userassociations__Email      | 1026 | const                 | 3 | 10.00 | Using where                     |
| 10 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | usercustomerflags |  | ref            | usercustomerflags_UserID_idx                                                                | usercustomerflags_UserID_idx |  144 | sterling.users.UserID | 1 | 10.00 | Using where                     |
|  8 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | usercustomerflags |  | index_subquery | usercustomerflags_CustomerFlagID_idx,usercustomerflags_UserID_idx                           | usercustomerflags_UserID_idx |  144 | func                  | 1 | 4.95  | Using where                     |
|  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | quoterequests     |  | index_subquery | quoterequests_CompanyID,quoterequests_UserID,quoterequests__Latest,quoterequests_UserQuotes | quoterequests__Latest        |  145 | func                  | 2 | 5.00  | Using where                     |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | invoices          |  | index_subquery | Invoice_UserID_idx,Invoice_CompanyID_idx,invoices_SampleRequests,invoices_LateOrdersBubble  | Invoice_UserID_idx           |  145 | func                  | 1 | 3.33  | Using where                     |
+----+--------------------+-------------------+--+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+------+-----------------------+---+-------+---------------------------------+

+----+--------------------+-------------------+--+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+------+-----------------------+--------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | users             |  | ref | fk_users_1_idx,users_Customers                                                              | users_Customers                |    4 | const                 | 227515 | 100.00 | Using where |
| 12 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | usercustomerflags |  | ref | usercustomerflags_UserID_idx                                                                | usercustomerflags_UserID_idx   |  144 | sterling.users.UserID |      1 | 10.00  | Using where |
| 10 | SUBQUERY           | usercustomerflags |  | ALL | usercustomerflags_CustomerFlagID_idx,usercustomerflags_UserID_idx                           |                                |      |                       |   3509 | 4.94   | Using where |
|  8 | SUBQUERY           | userquotesemails  |  | ref | userquotesemails_Email__Active,userquotesemails_UserID                                      | userquotesemails_Email__Active | 1027 | const,const           |      1 | 100.00 |             |
|  6 | SUBQUERY           | userassociations  |  | ref | userassociations_UserID,userassociations__Email                                             | userassociations__Email        | 1026 | const                 |      3 | 10.00  | Using where |
|  4 | SUBQUERY           | quoterequests     |  | ref | quoterequests_CompanyID,quoterequests_UserID,quoterequests__Latest,quoterequests_UserQuotes | quoterequests_CompanyID        |  144 | const                 |  16702 | 10.00  | Using where |
|  2 | SUBQUERY           | invoices          |  | ref | Invoice_UserID_idx,Invoice_CompanyID_idx,invoices_SampleRequests,invoices_LateOrdersBubble  | Invoice_CompanyID_idx          |  144 | const                 |  17678 | 10.00  | Using where |
+----+--------------------+-------------------+--+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+------+-----------------------+--------+--------+-------------+
```

Also, I've tried using joins, e.g. joining the `invoices` table, etc. but then I get the issue of having duplicate user rows per each `invoice` or `quoterequest` the joins receive, and grouping/distinct & ordering the resulting data became immensely slow, in the minutes.

I've also tried just the "exists" version of the first query, as suggesting by the doc https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html like so

```
select`UserID`
from`users`
where(`CompanyID`in('3e55d1bb-d8b6-11e4-b38f-b8ca3a83b4c8')
    or exists(select 1 
        from`invoices`
        where`CompanyID`in('3e55d1bb-d8b6-11e4-b38f-b8ca3a83b4c8')
        and`__Active`=1 
        and`users`.`UserID`=`UserID`)
    or exists(select 1 
        from`quoterequests`
        where`CompanyID`in('3e55d1bb-d8b6-11e4-b38f-b8ca3a83b4c8')
        and`__Active`=1 
        and`users`.`UserID`=`UserID`))
and(exists(select 1 
        from`userassociations`
        where`_Email`='brian@yeet.com'
        and`__Active`=1 
        and`users`.`UserID`=`UserID`))
and(exists(select 1 
        from`usercustomerflags`
        where`CustomerFlagID`in(10,27,17,1,2,3,4,5,6)
        and`__Active`=1 
        and`users`.`UserID`=`UserID`)
    or not exists(select 1 
        from`usercustomerflags`
        where`__Active`=1 
        and`users`.`UserID`=`UserID`))
and`Deleted`=0 
order by`DateTimeAdded`desc 
limit 50;
```

But that gets me up to 5.516s, so that definitely doesn't seem like the right direction to make.

What is the most efficient way to select data the way that I'm trying? Or do I need to restructure some of my tables to get the performance I'm looking for?

---

I've isolated the smallest sub-problem and bottle neck I think I have. Here's my lighter query

```
select`users`.`UserID`,`users`.`_Customer`
from`users`
left join`userassociations`on`userassociations`.`UserID`=`users`.`UserID`
and`userassociations`.`__Active`=1 
where(`users`.`Email`='brian@stumpyinc.com'
    or`userassociations`.`_Email`='brian@stumpyinc.com')
and`users`.`Deleted`=0 
order by`users`.`DateTimeAdded`desc 
limit 50;
```

And the explain

```
+---+--------+------------------+--+-----+--------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-----+-----------------------+--------+--------+-------------+
| 1 | SIMPLE | users            |  | ref | users_getemail_INDEX,unify_email_INDEX,users_Customers | users_Customers         |   4 | const                 | 221463 | 100.00 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | userassociations |  | ref | userassociations_UserID                                | userassociations_UserID | 144 | sterling.users.UserID |      1 | 100.00 | Using where |
+---+--------+------------------+--+-----+--------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-----+-----------------------+--------+--------+-------------+
```

This query takes about 1.5 seconds to execute

---

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `UserID` char(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ...
  `Email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    ...
  `DateTimeAdded` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    ...
  `Deleted` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ...
  `_LatestInvoiceDateTimeAdded` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `_InvoiceCount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `_Customer` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UserID_UNIQUE` (`UserID`),
    ...
  KEY `users_getemail_INDEX` (`Email`(191),`_InvoiceCount`,`_LatestInvoiceDateTimeAdded`,`DateTimeAdded`),
  KEY `unify_email_INDEX` (`Email`(191),`UserID`),
    ...
  KEY `users_Customers` (`Deleted`,`DateTimeAdded`),
    ...
  KEY `users_DateTimeAdded` (`DateTimeAdded`,`UserID`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `users_FULLTEXT__Customer` (`_Customer`),
    ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `userassociations` (
   `UserAssociationID` binary(16) NOT NULL,
   `UserID` char(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `AssociatedUserID` char(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `_Email` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `__UserID` char(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `__Active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   `__Added` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
   `__Updated` timestamp(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
   PRIMARY KEY (`UserAssociationID`),
   KEY `userassociations_UserID` (`UserID`),
   KEY `userassociations_AssociatedUserID` (`AssociatedUserID`),
   KEY `userassociations___UserID` (`__UserID`),
   KEY `userassociations__Email` (`_Email`),
   CONSTRAINT `userassociations_AssociatedUserID` FOREIGN KEY (`AssociatedUserID`) REFERENCES `users` (`UserID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `userassociations_UserID` FOREIGN KEY (`UserID`) REFERENCES `users` (`UserID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `userassociations___UserID` FOREIGN KEY (`__UserID`) REFERENCES `users` (`UserID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

---

Hmm... So it seemed like it was working, but I've found a pair of tables that it doesn't seem to be as efficient with, which is my `users` and `invoices` tables.

I've have these indexes:

```
users:    INDEX(`CompanyID`, `Deleted`, `DateTimeAdded`) 
invoices: INDEX(`UserID`, `__Active`) 
invoices: INDEX(`CompanyID`)
users:    INDEX(`UserID`, `Deleted`)
```

and the query

```
select`users`.`UserID`,`users`.`DateTimeAdded`
from`users`
join`invoices`on`invoices`.`UserID`=`users`.`UserID`
and`invoices`.`__Active`=1 
where`invoices`.`CompanyID`='3e55c8b4-d8b6-11e4-b38f-b8ca3a83b4c8'
and`users`.`Deleted`=0 
order by`DateTimeAdded`desc 
limit 200;
```

This query alone takes .3 seconds, which feels slow to me, like it isn't making the best use of the indexes, especially because `users` only has 430,997 rows and `invoices` only has 194,180, and this looks like it should be a pretty simple query.

EDIT: Actually it's much worse than that, if the CompanyID given only includes ~4 rows, then this query takes 3.5 seconds

```
+---+--------+----------+--+-----+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----+--------------------------------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| 1 | SIMPLE | invoices |  | ref | Invoice_CompanyID_idx,invoices_UserID___Active | Invoice_CompanyID_idx | 144 | const                          | 7750 | 10.00  | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | SIMPLE | users    |  | ref | users_UserID_Deleted                           | users_UserID_Deleted  | 148 | sterling.invoices.UserID,const |    1 | 100.00 |                                              |
+---+--------+----------+--+-----+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----+--------------------------------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Are `Email` and `_Email` separate columns?!  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: @RickJames Yes those are separate columns on separate tables, our underscores before a column denote that it's denormalized, and I've pasted them! Most of them, the users table has a lot of columns...

Comment: @RickJames woah, just read your comment on the answer below and applied it to my last query here, and that worked like magic

Comment: @RickJames oh ha, never mind, that's because it limits my result set by `userassocaitions` being active or not, regardless of users email matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that smaller problem:

```
( select u.`UserID`, u.`_Customer`, u.DateTimeAdded
    from  `users` AS u
    where  u.`Email` = 'brian@stumpyinc.com'
      and  u.`Deleted` = 0
      AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `userassociations`
                       WHERE UserId = u.UserID
                         AND __Active = 1 )
    order by  u.`DateTimeAdded` desc
    limit  50
)
UNION DISTINCT
( select u.`UserID`, u.`_Customer`, u.DateTimeAdded
    from  `users` AS u
    JOIN  `userassociations` AS ua
         ON  ua.`UserID` = u.`UserID`
        and  ua.`__Active` = 1
    where  ua.`_Email` = 'brian@stumpyinc.com' 
      and  u.`Deleted`=0
    order by  u.`DateTimeAdded` desc
    limit  50
)
order by `DateTimeAdded` desc
limit  50
```

These will be needed:

```
u:  INDEX(Email, Deleted, DateTimeAdded)  -- date last
ua: INDEX(UserId, __Active)   -- either order
ua: INDEX(_Email)
u:  INDEX(UserID, Deleted)
```

(Let me know if you get syntax errors.  If it is too slow, please provide `EXPLAIN`.)

Index prefixing (`Email(191)`) is usually useless.  Get rid if it.  Here are 5 ways to avoid it:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes

A PK is a UNIQUE key, so get rid of the second of:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`UserID`),
UNIQUE KEY `UserID_UNIQUE` (`UserID`),
```

Smells like a UUID; use ascii (ascii_general_ci), not utf8mb4:

```
... char(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

`INT(1)` takes 4 bytes; use `TINYINT` for flags.

Comment: I figured you'd go through my columns and their types :) I love your answers by the way, and this answer does indeed work so far, even with my 6 other tables I'm checking emails for. It gets a little more complicated because I do the same thing with companies, but I'll see if I can implement this exactly into what I'm building

Comment: Also, I don't think I need the `exists` on the first block, since I'm left joining

Comment: Damn, that worked wonders. Seriously, thanks. I've written every query we'd possibly need based on the strategy and works pretty much perfectly in all situations. Dynamically building this might be a bit tricky, but it can be done :) Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helps.  Dynamic query generation is often worth investing some time in.  The usual red flag is `WHERE 1=1 AND ...`

Comment: @RickJames From what I can see, the two main changes in the query itself were to 1) split the query to two, in order to avoid the OR clause and allow indexing, and 2) convert the LEFT join to an EXISTS subquery. Can you explain why the latter assists in this case? Why the EXISTS subquery will perform better than the LEFT JOIN?

Comment: (Not sure about _this_ case, but...)  `LEFT JOIN` will find all matching rows; `EXISTS` stops when _one_ matching row is found.  Depending on indexes, etc, `EXISTS` _may_ (or may not) be a lot faster.

Comment: @RickJames it looks like I've run into an issue with this strategy a bit, I've appended everything to my original question

Comment: @RickJames Now it takes ~3.5s :/

Comment: @BrianLeishman - "now" -- meaning after you made some change?  If so, what?

Comment: @RickJames It was the same strategy, but with different tables, and I just was testing this one very thoroughly

Comment: Let's see the EXPLAIN -- sounds as if it picked a different query plan.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can replace all those subqueries in the `WHERE` clause with a combination of `INNER` and `LEFT JOIN`s. Try this:

```
SELECT u.UserID 
FROM users u
INNER JOIN userassociations ua ON ua.userid = u.userid
LEFT JOIN usercustomerflags uc ON uc.userid = u.userid AND uc.__Active =1
LEFT JOIN invoices i ON i.userid = u.userid AND i.__Active =1
LEFT JOIN quoterequests q ON q.userid = u.userid AND q.__Active =1
WHERE ua._Email ='brian@yeet.com'
AND ua.__Active =1
AND (uc.userid IS NULL 
        OR (uc.userid IS NOT NULL AND uc.CustomerFlagID IN (10,27,17,1,2,3,4,5,6))
    )
AND (u.CompanyID = '3e55d1bb-d8b6-11e4-b38f-b8ca3a83b4c8'
        OR (i.CompanyID = '3e55d1bb-d8b6-11e4-b38f-b8ca3a83b4c8' AND i.userid IS NOT null)
        OR (q.CompanyID = '3e55d1bb-d8b6-11e4-b38f-b8ca3a83b4c8' AND q.userid IS NOT null)
    )
AND u.Deleted =0 
ORDER BY u.DateTimeAdded desc 
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: Yeah this was what I tried towards the end of my post where the speed here is fantastic as well, but the problem then is that I get duplicate customers because a user can (and often) have multiple invoices, flags, quote requests, etc.

Comment: I can throw a `distinct` at it, which is fine if the query only has a few users, but in the case of no longer filtering it by an email address, the query takes 18.828s, and a `group by u.UserID` takes 11.969s

Comment: Can you post the query plans for the different queries? You may be missing indexes somewhere that should help speed up your query(s).

Comment: I've added it to the question!

Comment: For this variant, I would have `ua`: `INDEX(_Email, __Active)`, `u`: `INDEX(userid)` and `INDEX(Deleted, DateTimeAdded)`.  The tests for `__Active =1` should probably be in the `WHERE` clause, not `ON`.

Comment: `INDEX(CompanyID, __Active, UserID)` is "covering, but contains a [_UUID_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid).

Comment: @RickJames, by putting the check for active=1 in the `LEFT JOIN` on clauses, we're filtering before the records get joined, preventing extraneous records where the right side ends up being NULL. This is especially important when checking `uc.userid IS NULL` in the `WHERE` clause.